# Screen Appears To Be Flickering (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, graphics, monitor, amd-graphics

Monitor: Benq XL2411Z
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon RX 460

This doesn't happen every time I boot the system and when I tried to record it the flickering didn't appear so I might have to do with the monitor.

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware problem that would not be related to Ubuntu. If you can connect your computer to a TV or a different monitor, try that and see if the flickering is still there.

Comment: that has nothing to do with ubuntu.